# How to create a loop 1M with random numbers >100000

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

My teacher asked me to create a loop that will be executed 1M times.
I tried `for(long i=0;i<1000000;i++)`, but the program is crashing. The maximum number that the program accepts is 10.000.

Any ideas? Is this possible?

Also he asked me to create a random number >100.000. I am using `rand();`. Should I use a different method?

this is the code:

```
start_time = clock(); 
for(long i=0;i<1000000;i++){
   num1 = rand();
   num2=rand();
   gcd1(num1,num2);
}

end_time = clock();

elapsed_time = (end_time - start_time) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;

printf( "time is %.3f seconds\n", elapsed_time );
system("pause");
```

This the gcd:

```
int gcd1(int x, int y){
    int z;
    if (x<y)
        z=x+1;
    else if (y<x)
        z=y+1;
    do{
        z=z-1;
    }
    while((x%z!=0) or (y%z!=0));
        return z;
    }
}
```

Comment: I just created a random number especially for you: 100001.

Comment: What is "1M times"? One thousand? One million? One millisecond? Also, you really ought to post the code that is crashing. The loop you gave probably wouldn't crash without some help from the contents of the loop.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that for loop.  Edit your question with code that reproduces the error.  Are you storing the values in an array?

Comment: LOL, how did you create it?? I mean with code

Comment: What's happening inside the loop?

Comment: Please show the complete code that crashes. There is no reason why a for-loop from 0 to 1000000 would crash the program just by itself. What exactly do you mean by "crash"; what exactly happens when you run the program?

Comment: 1 Million times. I will try a for(i<10000) inside a for(i<100).

Comment: sadly this code isnt quite right: http://xkcd.com/221/, add 100,000 to it

Comment: @user622203: Please **update** your question with (1) the code you ran and (2) the error you got.  Please don't add comments to your own question.  Please **update** your question.

Comment: Fifth line, "gcd1(int1,int);" looks very suspect, you sure you're not supposed to be passing num1 and num2 as params there?

Comment: Um...... "(x%z!=0) or (y%z!=0))".  "or" ?? This compiles?  Also, you're not doing anything with the result of gcd(...).  Please try to post your _real_ code as much as possible.

Comment: I dont want to do anything with gcd result, just to calculate the running time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try your loop as

```
for (i = 0; i < 1000000; i++) {
   do num1 = rand(); while (num1 == 0);
   do num2 = rand(); while (num2 == 0);
   gcd1(num1, num2);
}
```

`rand()` can return 0. When it does that (after more than 10000 loops), your program will set `z` to 0 and attempt to divide by 0.

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with having a loop that runs from 0 to 1000000. The reason that your program is crashing is something else that you are doing in your program.

Answer (score 1):

Try one of the following:

- Step through the code in the debugger to find which line is crashing.
- Comment out lines in the loop (and after it) until it runs. Then uncomment things one by one to track down the culprit.

One suspcious thing I see off the bat: What type is `elapsed_time` declared as? You are doing what looks like integer (or quadword integer?) math on it, and then you tell `printf` to print it as a float. `printf` doesn't do intelligent type conversions for you or anything. If you feed it a variable of the wrong type, you are liable to get garbage, or a crash.

Comment: OK i did that. the num1 and num2=rand(); are crashing the loop.

Comment: @user622203 - Just to double-check, try commenting out the gcd1() call and uncommenting those two `rand()` calls. Sometimes a routine can munch the stack and you don't see the problem until the next function is called.

Answer (score 1):

in gcd

you have an extra close brace

if x == y then z is undefined; so bad things can happen

Answer (score 0):

use longs, to loop over longer ranges:

```
for (long i = 0; i < 1000000L; i++) {
    //do something
}
```

for large randoms, you could cast the return of rand() to long and multiply two together or something like that.  (Heh, probably showing my age by this answer... back when I was coding C regularly, int was only 16 bits. ;)

Comment: ...and we were **glad to have** those 16 bits!

Answer (score 0):

In this statement

```
while((x%z!=0) or (y%z!=0));
```

my compiler i(llvm-gcc-4.2) won't compile it.  I'm just learning c but I think you want to change the "or" to "||"